# Mapping 100+ url parameters in a spring rest get request

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm bit curious about mapping more than 100 request params in a single get request as request params without using any complex objects.

Example

```
public ResponseEntitiy<> getCustomerDetails (String params...)
```

Is there any cool way to achieve this without writing them one by one.

Comment: 100 parameters as String param1, String param2... String param100 is unmanagable (at least for me). As https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297970/6785908 suggested getting it into a Map makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpretation of "cool" is very subjective.

If you imply to have an implicit way of mapping request parameters, maybe using a `Map<String, String>` is a plausible solution:

```
public ResponseEntity<> getCustomerDetails
    (@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {}
```

Comment: getting it into Map<String, String> makes sense as OP don't want "complex" object.